# How can I prevent Eclipse from importing nested classes?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

Whenever I use nested classes, I give them names *not including* the outer class name, e.g.,
`MySomething.Kind` and not `MySomething.MySomethingKind`. The nested classes are sometimes visible to the outside and then I want to refer to them always by the name qualified by the enclosing class, i.e., `MySomething.Kind` and not just `Kind`. Sometimes there are multiple classes containing a nested `Kind`, so using the unqualified name may be confusing.

Is there any way to prevent Eclipse from needlessly importing `mypackage.MySomething.Kind` instead of using (already imported) `mypackage.MySomething` together with the *semi-qualified* name?

#### UPDATE:

This doesn't happen spontaneously. As stated by [jprete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122241/jprete), when I always use the semi-qualified name, the nested class doesn't get imported. But any refactoring creating a variable of type `MySomething.Kind` declares it as `Kind` only and adds the unwanted import statement. This turns the refactoring to useless, as I have to edit it manually. Whenever I forget, I get the worst of both: a mixture of unqualified and semi-qualified names.

Comment: If my answer isn't sufficient, then can you add more information about your particular use case?

Comment: [The issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=305205) is on Bugzilla since 2010 :(

Answer (score 1):

I have found that, if I always refer to the nested class with the "semi-qualified" name - i.e. `MySomething.Kind` rather than `Kind` - that Eclipse will *not* try to automatically add `import mypackage.MySomething.Kind` when I tell it to reorganize imports, but instead will only add `import mypackage.MySomething` and leave the "Class.NestedClass" references alone.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's no solution, but what I'm doing now is pretty practical (when used in a script):

```
find src -name "*.java" | xargs perl -pi -e \
        's/^(import [.\w]+\.)([A-Z]\w+)(\..*);/$1$2;/;'
```

It simply replaces all the unwanted imports like

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
```

by the outer class imports like

```
import java.util.Map;
```

It's matter of seconds to fix the errors manually and let organize imports get rid of duplicates. It ignores static imports as I want.

**Warnings:**

- it touches all files ([solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29398029/581205))
- you have to refresh them in eclipse
- it modifies the source code, which is something *nobody should do without a source control*