# How to replace a string in an existing file in Perl while not touching unchanged files

Tags: perl, file

Using

```
perl -pi -e 's/pattern/replacement/g' $(find src -type f)
```

is nice, except for one thing: All files get overwritten, even those without any match. This is not good as I often keep many of them open in Emacs or Eclipse which then ask me boring questions. Is there a simple way how to prevent touching unchanged files (Something like using grep in find is too much work, especially for complex patterns).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very first thing `-i` after opening a file is to `unlink` it, so that means you can't use `-i` on the files you don't want to modify.

```
find src -type f -exec grep -Pl 'pattern' {} + |
   xargs perl -i -pe's/pattern/replacement/g'
```

Of course, `grep` can already perform recursive searches, so unless you need to use `find` to filter the results further than you indicated, you can use

```
grep -Plr 'pattern' src |
   xargs perl -i -pe's/pattern/replacement/g'
```

---

Note: `cmd | xargs perl ...` can handle more files than `perl ... $( cmd )`.

Comment: Could you explain your note concerning `xargs`?

Comment: @maaartinus, There's a limit on the size of command lines. It's much larger than it used to be, but it's not that hard to reach. `xargs` solves that problem by launching the program more than once if necessary. For example, It'll do `foo file1 file2 ... file499` & `foo file500 file501 ... file999` instead doing `foo file1 file2 ... file999` if the latter isn't possible.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of passing every file to perl to be processed, preselect them yourself.

Find the files that have `pattern` in them:

```
grep -Plr 'pattern' src
```

Then use that instead of that `find` call:

```
perl -pi -e 's/pattern/replacement/g' $(grep -Plr pattern src)
```

Or even like this:

```
grep -Plr 'pattern' src | xargs perl -pi -e's/pattern/replacement/g'
```

This will also probably be faster because you're not processing files unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

> -p
>
> causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed:
>
> ```
> LINE:
> while (<>) {
>     ... # your program goes here
> } continue {
>     print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
> }
> ```
>
> -i[extension]
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/perl
> $extension = '.orig';
> LINE: while (<>) {
>     if ($ARGV ne $oldargv) {
>        if ($extension !~ /\*/) {
>            $backup = $ARGV . $extension;
>        }
>        else {
>            ($backup = $extension) =~ s/\*/$ARGV/g;
>        }
>        rename($ARGV, $backup);
>        open(ARGVOUT, ">$ARGV");
>        select(ARGVOUT);
>        $oldargv = $ARGV;
>     }
>     s/foo/bar/;
> }
> continue {
>     print;  # this prints to original filename
> }
> select(STDOUT);
> ```

Now, that means you can take this skeleton script, and modify restore the backup if no substitutions were made.